# Перегрузка страницы с помощью ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js

Доброго времени суток. У меня есть форма логина, с помощью `ajax` я проверяю ее подленность и вывожу ошибку (если она есть). Но при успешной авторизации мне надо перегрузить страницу. Как это сделать?

Вот форма

```
    <form id="login">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="username" required="true">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
                <input type="button" name="submit" id="send" value="Submit" onclick="wrongLogin()">
            </form>
```

***Ajax*** запрос

```
function wrongLogin() {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        console.dir(event);
        document.getElementById('errWrongLogin').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
    }else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
        console.dir('error');
    }
};
xhr.open('POST', '/login', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
var logInfo='email='+document.getElementById('email').value+'&password='+document.getElementById('password').value;
xhr.send(logInfo);
```

А так же обработка на сервере node js

```
    var express = require('express');
var sql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var pool=require('conn');
var er = ' ';

var sess ;

module.exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
    sess=req.session;
    var username = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    pool.pool.query('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email= "'+ username +'" OR Nick= "' + username + '"', function (err, rows, fields){
                if(err) throw err;
        else if(rows.length > 0 && password == rows[0].Password){
            console.log('Hello');
            sess.user = rows[0].Nick;
            sess.email = rows[0].Email;
            sess.idUser = rows[0].id;
            sess.fName = rows[0].FName;
            sess.lName = rows[0].LName;
                    console.log(sess.email);
            res.send(' ');
        }else {
            er = '<div id="login_form">'+'Неправильний логін або пароль'+'</div>';
                    res.send(er);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: проблема только в том что б при успешной авторизации перезагрузить страницу.Весь процес оброботки работает отлчино(хорошо).Тоесть если логин и пароль совпадает с базой в перегрузить страницу

Comment: гм. значит код вы показали не точный, потому что ошибка налицо... в любом случае, просто используйте location.reload(); в условии if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

Comment: Да прошу прощения. В буфере оказалась не та форма. Спасибо за замечание. Исправил

Comment: window.location.href="";

Comment: @HELOWORD насколько я знаю window.location на бекенде не работает, но именно там у меня происходит проверка.

Comment: возвращай <script>window.location.href=""; </script>   ;)

Comment: @HELOWORD Возможно(скорее всего) я чтото делаю не так, но заменив строку res.send(' '); на res.send('<script>window.location.href="http://192.168.0.94:3005/"; </script>'); ниего не поменялось(

Comment: @ItsMyLife а чем не подходит мой вариант с location.reload() ? а, кажется понял, у вас запрос "успешный" даже при ошибке...

Comment: @ИванПшеницын в том что перегрузить страницу мне надо только при успейшной авторизации. Когда она не успешная этого делать не надо. А ваш способ на сколько я понимаю перегрузит ее в любом случае.

Comment: @ItsMyLife и как же решить эту ситуацию? очевидный простой ответ в вашем случае - ответ от сервера либо пустой либо с ошибкой.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын Спасибо все получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы вам, в случае успеха, не возвращать от сервера пустой ответ и при пустом ответе - обновлять страницу?

Исправить на бекенде успешный ответ на пустой `res.send('');`
И на клиенте проверять

```
if(xhr.responseText)
    document.getElementById('errWrongLogin').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
else 
    location.reload();
```

Строго говоря, лучше использовать http-запросы по назначению: если у вас ошибка при авторизации - возвращать ошибку. Успешный ответ говорит о том, что все прошло правильно.

Comment: Тебя немного опередил товарищ выше. Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: Да я сам с собой соревнуюсь тут ))